# Calculate sum of a series using telescopy

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$A=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n n} {(n+2)!} $$

By using induction, one can show that $A = 1$ but I don't know how to solve this problem by using other methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac{2^n n}{(n+2)!}=\frac{2^n(n+2-2)}{(n+2)!}=\frac{2^n}{(n+1)!}-\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+2)!}$$

Now, use telescopy.

Comment: what does telescopy/telescopic sum means?

Comment: @MonK, check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) out. Telescopy covers the part of telescoping product too, which is quite similar to telescoping sum in principle.

Answer (score -1):

As written by Prasun Biswas you have:

$$A=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n n} {(n+2)!}$$

Observe that:

$$\frac{2^n n}{(n+2)!}=\frac{2^n(n+2-2)}{(n+2)!}=\frac{2^n}{(n+1)!}-\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+2)!}$$

So your sum becomes:

$$A=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{(n+1)!}-\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+2)!}$$

Which is:

$$A=1-\frac 23+\frac 23-\frac 13+\frac 13-...=1$$

Comment: Why duplicate the other answer?

Comment: It misses the final result

Comment: It does so on purpose, obviously, so you are ruining its purpose.

Comment: Well when someone asks something wants a complete answer and not only an hint...

Comment: Really? How do you know? And even if it were so, does this entail this is the way to proceed? Sorry but I am not following your reasoning.

Comment: We have different point of views, I'm ok with it so peace